# Chrome Driver not functioning preventing use of Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, selenium

I am trying to run a script with selenium using chromedriver as the driver.  I receive the following error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\samde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\samde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 10, in <module>
    options= chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\samde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\samde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I think this maybe a path issue, but am unsure how to fix it. I added the chromedriver location to PATH in "Environment Variables" when I installed the chrome driver. Its location/ path is : "C:\Web_Drivers".

When I call chromedriver in powershell, I receive the following message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Troubleshooting**

- You may want to try using a regular command prompt (rather than PowerShell) and see if that helps to resolve the issue.
- Another consideration may be if you placed the path to `chromedriver.exe` in your `User` path rather than your `System` path.
- You should log out and log in after updating your path variables. In some cases, you may need to restart the PC as well.

**Calling ChromeDriver**

Assuming ChromeDriver resides in your Windows path, use either `chromedriver` or `chromedriver.exe` in your script e.g.:

*ex. without `executable_path`*

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
```

*ex. with `executable_path`*

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver')
```

*ex. with `executable_path` and a variable*

```
chromedriver_path = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

---

**Other Options**

There are also several options for specifying the path to ChromeDriver directly:

- Assuming `chromedriver.exe` is in the same folder as your script:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```
- Specifying the full path to `chromedriver.exe` without `executable_path`:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
  ```
- Specifying the full path to `chromedriver.exe` with `executable_path`:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
  ```
- Specifying the full path to `chromedriver.exe` with `executable_path` and a variable:

  ```
  chromedriver_path = 'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver_path)
  ```

Be aware that while you can also use `C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe` and `C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe`, some Chromium\ChromeDriver forks may not accept `C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe`. In this instance, try using either `\\` or `/` instead.